# Azure VM Alert Rules Automation

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, scripting, alert

I want to create a script in azure which sets alert rules automatically. I created this script, it works fine but it is not automated and i need to make changes every time i apply it to new virtual machine which is in different resource group and has a different alert rule name.

```html
#Creating action group as object
$action = [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Management.Models.ActivityLogAlertActionGroup]::New("/subscriptions/5e0ec067-7409-4ede-ae47-ed0926bad2ee/resourceGroups/alert/providers/Microsoft.Insights/actiongroups/alertaction")

#Setting up condition as object
$condition1 = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria -MetricName "Percentage CPU" -MetricNameSpace "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -TimeAggregation Average -Operator GreaterThan -Threshold 96

$condition2 = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria -MetricName "Available Memory Bytes" -MetricNameSpace "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -TimeAggregation Average -Operator LessThan -Threshold 1000000000

$condition3 = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria -MetricName "Data Disk IOPS Consumed Percentage" -MetricNameSpace "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -TimeAggregation Average -Operator GreaterThan -Threshold 95

$condition4 = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria -MetricName "OS Disk IOPS Consumed Percentage" -MetricNameSpace "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -TimeAggregation Average -Operator GreaterThan -Threshold 95

$condition5 = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria -MetricName "VmAvailabilityMetric" -MetricNameSpace "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -TimeAggregation Average -Operator LessThan -Threshold 1


#creating alert rule for percentage CPU
Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "ClientName - Virtual machines - VM1 - PercentageCPU - Critical" -ResourceGroupName Alert -WindowSize 0:30 -Frequency 0:15 -TargetResourceScope "/subscriptions/5e0ec067-7409-4ede-ae47-ed0926bad2ee/resourceGroups/alert/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/VM1" -TargetResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -TargetResourceRegion "eastus" -Description "Action will be triggered when CPU usage is greater than Threshold" -Severity 0 -ActionGroup $action -Condition $condition1

#creating alert rule for Available Memory bytesaction
Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "ClientName - Virtual machines - VM1 - Available Memory Bytes - Critical" -ResourceGroupName Alert -WindowSize 0:30 -Frequency 0:30 -TargetResourceScope "/subscriptions/5e0ec067-7409-4ede-ae47-ed0926bad2ee/resourceGroups/alert/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/VM1" -TargetResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -TargetResourceRegion "eastus" -Description "Action will be triggered when Available Memory Bytes is less than Threshold" -Severity 0 -ActionGroup $action -Condition $condition2

#creating alert rule for Data Disk IOPS Consumed Percentage
Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "ClientName - Virtual machines - VM1 - Data Disk IOPS Consumed Percentage - Critical" -ResourceGroupName Alert -WindowSize 1:0 -Frequency 0:30 -TargetResourceScope "/subscriptions/5e0ec067-7409-4ede-ae47-ed0926bad2ee/resourceGroups/alert/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/VM1" -TargetResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -TargetResourceRegion "eastus" -Description "Action will be triggered when Data Disk IOPS usage is Greater than Threshold" -Severity 0 -ActionGroup $action -Condition $condition3

#creating alert rule for Data Disk IOPS Consumed Percentage
Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "ClientName - Virtual machines - VM1 - OS Disk IOPS Consumed Percentage - Critical" -ResourceGroupName Alert -WindowSize 1:0 -Frequency 0:30 -TargetResourceScope "/subscriptions/5e0ec067-7409-4ede-ae47-ed0926bad2ee/resourceGroups/alert/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/VM1" -TargetResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -TargetResourceRegion "eastus" -Description "Action will be triggered when OS Disk IOPS usage is Greater than Threshold" -Severity 0 -ActionGroup $action -Condition $condition4

#creating alert rule
Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "ClientName - Virtual machines - VM1 - VM Availability - Critical" -ResourceGroupName Alert -WindowSize 0:15 -Frequency 0:15 -TargetResourceScope "/subscriptions/5e0ec067-7409-4ede-ae47-ed0926bad2ee/resourceGroups/alert/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/VM1" -TargetResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -TargetResourceRegion "eastus" -Description "Action will be triggered when VM Availability is less than Threshold." -Severity 0 -ActionGroup $action -Condition $condition5
```

what step should i take to make this as an automation script for all virtual machines in different subscription and resource group and also with different alert name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you even tried. Start with the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-classic-portal#with-powershell), there is a lot of interesting stuff there.